# How to add user_signed_in? in template angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, slim-lang

I trying use user_signed_in? (gem devise) in app/assets/templates/index.html.slim

My code:

```
 - unless user_signed_in?
   li ng-click='login()'
     a href='javascript:void(0)' translate='user.sign_in'
   li ng-click='register()'
     a href='javascript:void(0)' translate='user.sign_up'
  - else
     li
      a href=profile_path(current_user.id)
```

It show error : "underfine method user_signed_in?"

Information routes

```
destroy_user_session_path   DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   sessions#destroy
login_by_token_path     GET     /users/login_by_token/:token(.:format)  api/v1#api_user2
user_password_path  POST    /password(.:format)     front/passwords#create
new_user_password_path  GET     /password/new(.:format)     front/passwords#new

cancel_user_registration_path   GET     /cancel(.:format)   front/registrations#cancel
user_registration_path  POST    /   front/registrations#create
new_user_registration_path  GET     /sign_up(.:format)  front/registrations#new
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missing

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

in conrtoller, that related with this template.